# Deleting last item from RecyclerView does not work

Tags: java, android, logging, android-recyclerview, adapter

I have a recycler view

A user can delete or add an item in the `RecyclerView`.

Everything works fine until the `RecyclerView` reaches 1 element.

When I needed to delete the last item, it does not get deleted. The log shows that the item is removed from the `ArrayList`, but it still shows in the `RecyclerView`.

Is something more needed when deleting the last item ?

Code :

```
public void removeItem(int adapterPosition){
       arrayList.remove(adapterPosition);
       Log.. ///
}
```

When `adapterPosition` is 0, it does not remove the item.

I have even kept a breakpoint in the method, and it is still showing that the adapterPosition is 0.

Comment: No, it's just like deleting any other item

Comment: But it is not getting deleted ?

Comment: There's probably a bug in your code - you'd have to post a [mre] to know for sure, though

Comment: Precisely, Not the last element. The first element in the recycler view does not get deleted.

Comment: Actually, I think I see the problem...I added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `notifyItemRemoved` in order to inform the `RecyclerView` that the item has been removed.  This is necessary on every deletion/removal, not just the last one, but it may sometimes appear to work by coincidence if you don't.

That is, your `removeItem` method (assuming it's on your `Adapter`) should look like:

```java
public void removeItem(int adapterPosition){
    arrayList.remove(adapterPosition);
    notifyItemRemoved(adapterPosition);
    Log.. ///
}
```